# What does "CC=/path/to/directory ./configure" do?

Tags: bash, gcc, cc

What does `CC=/path/to/afl/afl-gcc ./configure` do? (see. [AFL's Readme](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/README.txt))

Is it *telling* GCC to look into that directory for files?
(Maybe something like a path-variable, because of the **=**-character?)

Strange thing also: there is no configure-exe. in that [directory](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/releases/afl-latest.tgz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
A=B C
```

The shell runs the command `C` with the environment variable `A` set to `B`.

The `CC` environment variable is commonly used to tell `configure` scripts where a C compiler is located.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of two actions:

1. Set the environment variable `CC` to `/path/to/afl/afl-gcc`
2. Execute ./configure (with that environment variable)

If both actions are on one line, the environent variable is only passed to this command and is not stored in the environment of the current shell.

The `CC` can be used to tell the configure script which c comiler to use.